# ¿Como solucionar la conexion PDO con PHP de inicio de sesion?

Tags: php, pdo

tengo un formulario de registro y de inicio de sesión creado en android studio, el cual antes lo tenia con la conexión mysqli y se iniciaba sesión sin problemas, pero cambie la conexión a PDO,el cual ahora no me inicia sesión, he realizados pruebas desde conexión local pero no me sale ningún error, alguien me puede orientar para ver si estoy haciendo algo mal con la conexión PDO.

**conexión con base de datos PDO**

```
<?php

   try{
   $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=logishuman;charset=utf8','root','');

   //echo 'Conexión exitosa';
  } catch (PDOException $e) {

   die("¡Error!: " . $e->getMessage());     
  }
 ?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

  include("conexion.php");

  $email = $_POST["email"];

  $pass = $_POST["pass"];

 if (empty($email) && empty($pass)) {
 echo "0";

 } else {
  $statement=$pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM t_usuario WHERE email=?');
  $statement->bindParam("s",$email);

  if ($statement->execute()) {
    $results = $statement->fetchAll();
    if ($results ->rowCount == 1) {
        $pass_hash = $results->fetch_assoc();
      
        
        if (password_verify($pass, $pass_hash["pass"])) {
            
            echo "1";
        }else {
            echo "2";
        }
    } else {
        echo "3";
     }

  }else {
    echo "4";
   }
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: @BetaM te refieres reemplazarlos por estos `bindParam` , `fetchAll`, `rowCount`

Comment: @BetaM ya edite la pregunta, y intente migrando pero igual no me inicia sesión.

Comment: intenta utilizando `$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` ya que `$results->fetch_assoc()` es de `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

Existen varios aspectos por corregir en la query que expones:

1. El método [`bindParam`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.bindparam.php) en el caso de PDO necesita al menos los siguientes argumentos:

   - parámetro
   - variable
   - tipo de dato (*considera especificarlo, pues por *default* siempre es `PDO::PARAM_STR`*)

- Dado lo anterior, entonces debe quedar de esta forma:

  ```
  bindParam(1, $email, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  ```

2. Del contexto de tu pregunta se asume que buscas encontrar solo un usuario que coincida con el email otorgado, entonces:

   - No necesitas el método [`fetchAll`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetchall.php) que te daría una matriz de resultados obtenidos (*ya que deberías iterar para acceder a los registros de solo un usuario, lo cual no suena práctico*)

- En cambio propongo uses el método [`fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) para solo obtener una fila de resultados quedando así:

  ```
   $usuarioEncontrado = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  ```

  - Si quieres saber mas del argumento pasado al método `fetch` recomiendo [leas aquí](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.constants.php#pdo.constants)
  - Para acceder a los valores devueltos por la consulta bastaría con algo como esto:

    ```
    echo $usuarioEncontrado["email"];
    ```
- En caso de no obtener resultados, estarías recibiendo un `false` como respuesta dado eso puedes sustituir el uso de `rowCount` por algo como esto:

  ```
    if ($usuarioEncontrado) {
        /*
            Aquí si existe el usuario
        */
    } else {
    /*
            Aquí no
    */
    }
  ```

3. Finalmente no esta demás que si solo vas a recuperar un registro de tu base de datos, entonces indiques ese límite en la query de esta forma:

   ```
   SELECT email, password .............. LIMIT 1;
   ```

Comment: BetaM esta sintaxis sirve también trabajar desde una aplicación móvil con android, es donde estoy haciendo el inicio de sesión no estoy en sitio web.

Comment: Yo *migré* tu código de funciones y propiedades de una clase (*mysqli*) a otra (*PDO*), este código trabajará siempre que uses PHP como lenguaje para interactuar con la data recibida producto del request así como la interacción con la base de datos (**como expones en tu pregunta**) (*aunque si ya estás programando en Java o Kotlin ¿por qué no mejor programar todo bajo alguno de esos lenguajes? en fin*)

Comment: BetaM, estoy programando en java con android studio en cual  ya estaba trabajando bien con la conexión mysqli , pero por querer crearlo en conexión PDO, por cuestion de inyección sql, pero me encontré con esos detalles, en tu respuesta si esta bien nomas que en los echo ya tengo las validaciones realizadas en front-end.

Comment: Si es por el echo que coloqué, solo era un ejemplo para que probaras el acceso a la información de la bd, por otro lado como te digo el lenguaje sigue siendo el mismo (PHP) la conexión y el modo de trabajo cambio pero eso no implica que ahora dicho script no sea capaz de hacer las consultas y respuestas apropiadas como lo hacias con mysqli, por otro lado creo que no revisaste a detalle la doc,. de mysqli, pues esta última también permite consultas preparadas como PDO lo cual supone agregar seguridad contra inyecciones sql

Comment: BetaM y como te quedo mi código ya con la migrado a PDO, estoy mi teléfono no he podido ver bien tu respuesta llagando a casa lo checo bien ya en mi computadora,  revise algo leve sobre la documentación  de sentencias preparadas y procedimientos almacenados por cuestión de tiempo no estuve de lleno ya que hay mucha documentación.